# Why is SVG-import importing the wrong image in React?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am trying to import an SVG-File as a React Component. This works fine in other files I am working on. But in the one I have a problem with, instead of the correct image, another image is displayed.

```
import React from 'react';
import './news-detail.style.css';
import Header from '../header/header.component';
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import CustomButton from '../custom-button/custom-button.component';
import { ReactComponent as Img } from './newsdetail.svg';


const NewsDetail = props => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return <div className='news-detail'>
        <Header/>
        <h1 className="pageheadline">News</h1>
        <CustomButton onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Back</CustomButton>  
        <Img className="headerimg"/>
        </div>;
};


export default NewsDetail;
```

This is my code. The newsdetail.svg is not displayed. Instead, a component from my Header is displayed as the image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you checked the dev tools? Is your element visible at the DOM tree? It might be CSS, you got typo: className="headering"

Answer (score 0):

Check the id, class, or style properties present in the SVG file and verify whether the other SVG file uses the same id, class, or style. If so that's the reason why it loads a different image on SVG.

Using different variables in each SVGs will fix this issue. Make sure that when you update the variable, update all the occurrences of that variable in that SVG file.